# Mysql sorting of a table on the base of other table

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have two tables, Products and sales. In products table all  users add products. And when a sale is made, the sale table is updated with all info about product including user who added that product.

Products Table

**`id|Product Name|User|Price|Date`**

Sales Table

**`id|Product Name|Quantity|Seller|Price`**

Where Seller and User have same value

My question is that when I display products, I want them in order that the user who selles more products, his all products should be at top and other users who have products in Products Table but have no any sell should be at bottom.

Comment: Do you already have written your model ? In that case, could you create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some mock data ?

Comment: Just count the number of sells per user, and order by that column

Comment: PLease elaborate "Now I want to query all the products in way that the user who has sold one or more products his products should be at top, 2nd should at second place and 3rd on 3rd place and so on.."

Answer (score 3):

so this is only table name and column name assumptions:

```
SELECT   a.UserID, 
         Count(a.ProductID) as TotalCount
  FROM   Sales a INNER JOIN Products b
           ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
GROUP BY a.UserID
ORDER BY TotalCount desc
```

**UserID**  is the id the of the person who sells product 
**ProductID** is the ID of your product and it is the field that connects the two tables 
**COUNT()** is the name of the Aggregate function which counts the records for every user.

***PS: Please include in your question the schema of your table.***

**UPDATE 1**

If that's the case, you will have to use`LEFT JOIN`:

```
  SELECT a.ProductName,
         COUNT(b.Seller) as TotalSellerCount
    FROM Products a LEFT JOIN Sales b
       ON a.User = b.Seller
GROUP BY a.ProductName
ORDER BY TotalSellerCount desc
```

Comment: I have try something like this but in this query I get the only product for which I have sale record. Other products who have no sale will not display. I want all the products but in order that the user who has more sells should be at top.